# Some files missing in Vercel source/output files after build

Tags: deployment, build, next.js, production, vercel

I have a blog project in production. If I check the deployment source under output tab, some files are missing in pages folder. It shows "no output files."

This is not affecting surfing the blog, everything works fine. The build log is perfect as well, no errors or warnings. What I realized is that all the missing pages in the Vercel output folder can't be crawled by search engines, so they suffer SEO.

Vercel is picking the files from my git commit so it's automatic once I commit to main. The deployment settings wasn't tampered with so it's the default for a NextJS project as set by Vercel, and the build log shows that all these missing files were successfully generated.

I've searched everywhere online, I saw someone with similar problem on one blog like that but no solution to it yet. I contacted Vercel, they said maybe it's NextJS specific issue which I strongly doubt, still no solution provided.

I wonder why pages will be successfully generated yet they won't appear in the Vercel output folder.

[image: Vercel screenshot]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After days of no solution, I opened another complaint with Vercel and another agent was assigned to me. I was told that the 'missing files' in Source folder is not missing exactly, but there was a bug in their File Tree component. I can confirm now that the files are now visible in in Vercel source folder, perhaps, this bug has been attended to.

**EDIT**

After another commit, the *No source files* error still showed but got fixed after re-deploying the commit from Vercel.